# What's the difference between APB1 peripheral clocks and APB1 Timer clocks in STM32?

Tags: timer, microcontroller, stm32f4

Thank you for visiting my question.
I'm now trying to set up my STM32 device(NUCLEO STM32F401RE) to use timer and found that which clock the timer is working based on.
TIM2 is used so the clock signal should come from APB1.

[Bus info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zKSn.png)

Below is my clock configuration.

[Clock config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWoIg.png)

Here I have some questions. There are two clocks: APB1 peripheral clocks and APB1 Timer clocks.

1. What's the difference of these? Why are these separated, one is prescaled and the other is not?
2. On which clock the TIM2 works based after all?

Comment: did you look at the st documentation for the clock tree for this device?  and the control registers?

Comment: APB1 is just the bus the peripherals are on

Comment: I have been looking for the Bus Info table all over the place but I am not able to find it. Can you please let me know where you source it from?

Comment: I just found it [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0368-stm32f401xbc-and-stm32f401xde-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It can be the difference between peripheral's configuration registers, that you access via APB1 with APB1 speed, and the clock timer, that ticks the counter of the clock.

Here is a clock tree section of RCC peripheral of STM32F401 reference manual RM0368, page 94:

[image]

Page 95:

[image]

And right after that is yet another interesting piece:

[image]

The last piece talks about configuration that isn't often mentioned, I've usually seen it by default, but hey, you have quite a bit a flexibility here.

In default scenario, if APB clock is not equal to system clock (i.e. APB prescaler is greater than 1), then Timer counter clocks are doubled.

So if my MCU runs at 48MHz and APB1 is also 48MHz, I access timer's registers at 48MHz, and the timer (at timer prescaler=1) ticks at 48MHz.

But if my MCU runs at 84MHz, but my APB1 runs at 42MHz, then I access timer's registers at 42MHz, but the timer (at timer prescaler=1) ticks at 84MHz.

Very often, when your MCU is at max system clock frequency, APB bus will have a prescaler greater than one, meaning the timers' counters run at double their bus speed.

Comment: @llya
Thank you for your answer.
So you mean if system clock, APB1 peripheral clock and APB1 timer clock are 84, 42 and 84 MHz, respectively, the timer ticks at 84 MHz while the CPU accesses the timer at 42 MHz?

Comment: @mamo precisely.